# ArrayList contains wrong type objects without explicit raw-type casting

Tags: java, android, generics, type-safety, gson

Can anyone suggest how given code could possibly result in such issue, giving occasional `ClassCastException` when data is parsed from file.

Details :

I have a generic methods in superclass.

```
public T getItem(int position) {
     return mItems.get(position); // mItems is an ArrayList
}
// corresponding setter
public void setItems(List<T> items) {
    mItems = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

It is then used in subclass with T = `AdItem` as below :

```
AdItem adItem = getItem(position);
```

Everything works fine, but I got occasional production crash reports with exception at the above mentioned line:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to .mypackage.AdItem`

which obviously indicates that list contains `LinkedTreeMap` instead of `AdItem`

The list is parsed from json, and the code is type safe, i.e. no raw type casting, unchecked warnings, etc.

**What are scenarios for `ArrayList<AdItem>` to contain `LinkedTreeMap` objects runtime ?**
Except for explicit unchecked/raw-type casting to `Object` and back to `ArrayList` which is not the case.

Parsing json from file :

```
ArrayList<AdItem> tempList = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, typeToken.getType());
```

where

```
typeToken = new TypeToken<ArrayList<AdItem>>() {};
```

so `tempList` should only contain `AdItem`.

Can anyone explain how ClassCastException could possibly happen with the code above ? Any extra details will be provided on request.

Comment: Try debugging, with a breakpoint set right after an LinkedTreeMap enters your list. Hopefully your IDE/Debugger will allow to create such complicated breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

By default it deserialize a JSON object into a LinkedHashMap if it does not recognize the provided type properly.

Use code as give below to get the type and try again:

```
TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class,AdItem.class)

or

new ObjectMapper().getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class,AdItem.class) // In case you are using ObjectMapper
```

i.e.

```
ArrayList<AdItem> tempList = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class,AdItem.class));
```

Comment: I will give it a try, +1 for help